# No idea why I'm getting an assertion error here

Tags: java, runtime-error

So, I'm doing this exercise on edabit for fun, and I got an assertion error. The goal of the exercise is to check and see if there are any numbers in an array that are higher than a given number. Here is my code.

```
public class ExistsANumberHigher {
    public static boolean existsHigher(int[] arr, int n) {
        boolean b = false;
        for(int num : arr){
            if(num > n){
                b = true;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

When given an array of [4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2], and a given number of 4, it throws an assertion error. I'm not even sure what an assertion error is. Not looking for improvements to my code other than fixing this error btw. It's a 2-minute challenge. Thank you.

Comment: Probably wants `>=` instead of `>`. The AssertionError just means you got their challenge wrong its not an error being thrown by your code.

Answer (score 0):

An `AssertionError` is thrown when you write an assertion:

```
void foo() {
  int x = 5;
  int y = 6;
  assert x > y;
}
```

asserts are normally not evaluated; the idea is that an assert is **not** used to verify inputs, solely to state truths, and they serve as documentation primarily. On runs while developing, you let them evaluate.

That you're getting them here is a bit odd; presumably the 'test framework' that checks your `existsHigher` impl is written as e.g.:

```
void checkWork() {
  assert ExistsANumberHigher.existsHigher(new int[] {4, 3, 3, 2, 2}, 4);
}
```

In ohter words, the testcode is broken or the question has a typo - that's my best guess. That they actually want 'higher or equal', so try `>=` and see what happens. Or just talk to whomever made this thing, they messed up.

Comment: I think i found the challenge: https://edabit.com/challenge/aWzxPLibBLJgn8AbZ - While the title says "Exists a number higher" the actual description reads "Write a function that returns true if there exists at least one number that is larger than or equal to n.". So yeah, its messed up and not setting a good example of having method names actually match their functionality.

Comment: thank you. Very helpful